# Sorting by votes on Information Security

Tags: support

I'm trying to view all the highest voted questions on https://security.stackexchange.com/ but tab with the options to sort which appear on the other sub-sites seems to be missing. Have I missed something here or is there another way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to be logged in for those tabs to appear. Side note: this is the meta for Stack Overflow. Security.SE has its own, and there's a global meta (http://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only see the newest tab without logging in. All tabs are visible only for logged in users.

However, you can manually append the parameter to the URL in the browser to sort by votes without logging in:

> https://security.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes